# Get image from rendering parameters

Tags: sitecore-client

I am using rendering parameters to render the image in view.

[image]

It is showing :-

```
<image mediaid="guid"/>
```

Instead of the image. Kindly assist me.

Comment: Please provide more detail to your question, including actual code that you are using rather than a photo of your screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in functionality to get image from Rendering Parameters. Instead you need to manually load xml and then get image by ID.
This code should get you on right track:

```
    var imageParam = RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Parameters["image"];
    var xml = XmlUtil.LoadXml(imageParam);
    var imageId = xml != null ? XmlUtil.GetAttribute("mediaid", xml) : string.Empty;
    var imageItem = Context.Database.GetItem(new ID(imageId));
```